# How to stop a program without checking a stop flag everywhere in the code?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to create a stop button that stops a threading process as in the example below. My problem is that in my real example the process is not a simple loop, but much more complex and including static functions that take quite some time. Therefore, I would have to convert the static functions to instance methods and check the stop flag everywhere in my code, which seems ugly to me.

Is there a way to tell python to check the stop flag every 2 seconds, no matter where in the process you are (even if you are in static functions), and return if the flag is True? I can imagine the tkinter after function might do this somehow but I don't know how.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

def static_counter():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.2)
    return 10

class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Counter")
        self.root.geometry('300x50+200+200')
        self.running = False
        self.asked_stop = False
        
        # buttons
        self.button_start = tk.Button(text="Start", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.process).start())
        self.button_start.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NWSE', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.button_stop = tk.Button(text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.button_stop.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NWSE', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.label_status_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_status_var.set("0")
        self.label_status = tk.Label(textvariable=self.label_status_var)
        self.label_status.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='NWSE', padx=5, pady=5)

        # configure
        for i in range(3):
            self.root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # mainloop
        self.root.mainloop()

    def stop(self):
        self.asked_stop = True

    def check_stop(self):
        if self.asked_stop:
            self.label_status_var.set("stopped")
            self.root.update()
            self.running = False
            self.asked_stop = False
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def process(self):
        # check already running
        if self.running:
            return
        else:
            self.label_status_var.set("0")
            self.running = True

        # process
        counter = 0
        while True:
            if self.check_stop():  # would have to put this everywhere, including static_counter()
                return
            counter += static_counter()
            self.label_status_var.set(str(counter))
            self.root.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = MyGUI()
```

Comment: Could this not solved with the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) handler?

Comment: @Hermann12 Signals can be useful for this kind of thing but you have to be very careful when/if interrupting something that might be "transactional"

Comment: You can implement a form of scheduling using signal.SIGALRM but **only** on Unix type operating systems

Answer (score 0):

You could change `static_counter()` to take a function that it checks:

```
def static_counter(f):
    for i in range(10):
        if f():
            return 0,True
        time.sleep(0.2)
    return 10,False
```

then your calling code within your thread could be like this:

```
        counter = 0
        while True:
            count,stop = static_counter(self.check_stop)
            if stop:
                return
            counter += count
            self.label_status_var.set(str(counter))
            self.root.update()
```

Comment: Solves the issue with the static functions, thanks for that, but I still would have to put the if-condition multiple times in the static functions? These are not simple for-loops in my real example. I'm searching for a way how to interrupt without checking everywhere.

Comment: I think that you will need to write a new question which is simpler than this question, but includes a few examples of your: `"not simple for-loops"`. This might elicit some suggestions for your requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help. Just think of 10 subsequent loops, I'd have to write `if f(): return 0, True` 10 times. What I'm thinking of is replacing the `while True` loop in the process function by something like `while not self.check_stop()`, but with the ability to kill any static function every two seconds or so?